# would adding redundant classes in the softmax affect the network performance?

Tags: neural-networks, softmax, optical-character-recognition

I'm training an OCR model for a non-Latin language with 40 chars.

I'll need to combine English at some point which will require some changes to the Architecture and training from scratch.

Would it be possible to add the set of all characters to the softmax(English chars and the other language chars) when training without english without affecting the performance?

If it won't affect the performance then that'll definitely help when adding the english dataset because I wouldn't need to train from scratch.

Thanks

Comment: training time is very costly

Comment: I think this is a good idea, I'd try it until I get a definitive answer

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out is to experiment with both approaches and see for yourself. If a full experiment is too costly because e.g., the data is too large, you could train on a small subset of data as a preliminary experiment.

Comment: @MohamedNabil please consider accepting the answer if this was helpful

Comment: thanks for your answer, sadly this doesn't satisfy my question I wanted a theoretical proof or experimental proof for this based on a research paper or mathematical proof 
doing the actual experiment myself is a good approach but it's not the answer to my specific question

Comment: @MohamedNabil Thanks for clarifying. Consider adding that to your question.